# System.PlatformNotSupportException: The Websocket protocol is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So after some researching, it looks like the Discord.Websocket uses libraries that aren't compatible with Windows 7. However, I wasn't able to find a proper work-around to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net). .NET Core 1.1 does not support WebSockets on Win7 and earlier. It's recommended to use the Discord.Net.Providers.WS4Net package until this is resolved

You can switch to using Ws4Net by configuring this in your `DiscordSocketConfig`

```
client = new DiscordSocketClient(
            new DiscordSocketConfig()
            {
                LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose,
                WebSocketProvider = anywebsocketprovider
            }
```